# Auto populating a master list from multiple cells in multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, list, auto-populate

I am trying to create an auto populated master list based on data housed in several worksheets. For example, each worksheet is assigned to a different individual, and if a specific box is marked with an "x", I would like that individual's name to be populated into a list on the master worksheet so that I can keep track of which individuals have been marked/flagged. Part of the trick would be that if cell A1 on the master worksheet already has an individual's name, then I would want the rule to apply for cell B1 (minus the previously named individual in A1), and so on. In addition, each worksheet would have multiple cells in which the individual may be flagged with an "x" (i.e., D7, D13, D20, etc.).

In the individual's worksheet I have already set it up so that if an "x" is marked in cell D7, then their name would generate in a hidden cell F7, but am not sure if this step is even helpful. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to make a table on the master sheet with all the names of the individuals, you could use IF statements to determine whether or not the "x" was marked on their sheet, and if so then display their name. If you wanted, you could then filter out the individuals on the master list that didn't have any flags.

> **Example:** The sheet for "John" has 2 cells that can be flagged: B2 and G6.
>   Your master list table has at least two columns: 'Name' and 'Flagged'.

In the 'Flagged' column next to John's name on the master list you would enter:

```
=IF(OR('JohnWorksheet'!$B$2="x",'JohnWorksheet'!$G$6="x"),"x","")
```

Every time you put an "x" in either B2 or G6 on John's worksheet, it would flag the master list as well.

For a slightly more complex formula that could accept any input as a flag, and not just "x", you could put:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK('JohnWorksheet'!$B$2)=FALSE,ISBLANK('JohnWorksheet'!$G$6)=FALSE),"x","")
```

You could apply a filter to the 'Flagged' column to remove the unflagged individuals. Filtering out the unflagged names from the list has one slight hiccup: the table filters in Excel don't update automatically if the data changes; you have to refresh them manually by clicking somewhere within the table, going into the "Data" tab and clicking "Reapply" under "Sort & Filter". If you wanted to use a bit of VBA, you could make this into a keyboard shortcut, or even make it happen automatically whenever a cell updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!! Another question...or possible hiccup... if the worksheets name is something generic like "Student 1" to start with and as we use the sheet we will change the name of the worksheet (I.e., "John"), is there a way to have the master list account for this??

Comment: Based on your suggestion, each name would be assigned to a specific row on the master list, if I am understanding correctly. Is there any way for each row to account for any worksheet in the document, and once a name was populated in the master list, the subsequent row would read the formula for each additional sheet excluding the name already populated? And then each time a row was filled that name was no longer considered in the master list?

Comment: @ErinAnderson you can get the sheet name using the formula `=RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)))` and replace `'JohnWorksheet'` with that.

Comment: @ErinAnderson I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to accomplish with these rows accounting for any worksheet in the document. Can you try to explain your overall goal, or what you hope to do with this? Perhaps this might be easier to solve as a separate question; you could link to this one and then expand on it.